# PostgreSQL -- Ordering resuts depending on 2 columns logically grouped

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine a table like this over 100 fields and I shrink it

```
     the_id | company        |   abcd     | master_id
   ---------+----------------+------------+------------------
        500 | M-803          |            |                0
        501 | M-803          |            |                0
        502 | M-803          |            |                0
        503 | M-803          |            |                0
        504 | M-803          |            |                0
        507 | M-803          | 45 KK 526  |              505
        506 | M-803          | ARC0032    |              505
        505 | M-803          | 355 KKK 65 |                0
        476 | M-803          |            |                0
        508 | M-803          | ARC0032    |              504
        515 | N-0052         |            |                0
        516 | N-0052         |            |                0
        517 | N-0052         |            |                0
        518 | N-0052         |            |                0
        519 | N-0052         | 42 FDR 03  |              515
```

I want to order the query result like this

```
     the_id | company        |   abcd     | master_id
     -------+----------------+------------+------------------
        500 | M-803          |            |                0
        501 | M-803          |            |                0
        502 | M-803          |            |                0
        503 | M-803          |            |                0
        504 | M-803          |            |                0
        508 | M-803          | ARC0032    |              504
        505 | M-803          | 355 KKK 65 |                0
        507 | M-803          | 45 KK 526  |              505
        506 | M-803          | ARC0032    |              505
        476 | M-803          |            |                0
        515 | N-0052         |            |                0
        519 | N-0052         | 42 FDR 03  |              515
        516 | N-0052         |            |                0
        517 | N-0052         |            |                0
        518 | N-0052         |            |                0
```

First master id then detail fields grouped

Any ideas?

Comment: I've gone ahead any removed the tag spam. [Edit] your question to tag properly please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is dbms realated, its more tobe sql realted.. I'm using postgresql

Comment: you could concatenate some columns and order by the concatenated column?

Comment: Can you explain the ordering logic you need, it is not clear when looking at the expected query result. In any case, you can order a query according to any list of columns of the queried tables in the FROM clause and/or fields in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

I sort it out by "concatenate some columns" like sebastian siemens said..

```
SELECT  ( 
     (case 
        when master_id = 0 then 
            RPAD(the_id::varchar,10,'0') 
        else 
            RPAD(master_id::varchar,10,'0') 
     end) 
      ||RPAD(the_id::varchar,10,'0') )as TheNEwID
,*
from table
ORDER BY TheNEwID ASC
```

TheNEwID|the_id | company        |   abcd     | master_id
----------------+----------------+------------+------------------
500500  |   500 | M-803          |            |                0
501501  |   501 | M-803          |            |                0
502502  |   502 | M-803          |            |                0
503503  |   503 | M-803          |            |                0
504504  |   504 | M-803          |            |                0
504508  |   508 | M-803          | ARC0032    |              504
505505  |   505 | M-803          | 355 KKK 65 |                0
505507  |   507 | M-803          | 45 KK 526  |              505
505506  |   506 | M-803          | ARC0032    |              505
515515  |   515 | N-0052         |            |                0
515519  |   519 | N-0052         | 42 FDR 03  |              515
516516  |   516 | N-0052         |            |                0
517517  |   517 | N-0052         |            |                0
518518  |   518 | N-0052         |            |                0

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add your request, and so maybe help other people that will come on your question ?

Comment: As displayed above, 507 and 506 are out of order per this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want the `master_id` to take priority over `the_id` when it's non-zero:

```
order by case when master_id <> 0 then master_id else the_id end
```

That could also be written using `coalesce()` if you prefer to think of it as a merging operation. If you've got null values rather than zeroes then the `nullif()` is unnecessary:

```
order by coalesce(nullif(master_id, 0), the_id)
```

It's not clear to me whether you want to sort next by a secondary detail value like `abcd` or by the non-master `the_id`.

Comment: master_id is not null and always 0 if no value assigned..

Comment: Burak, which is why I compared it against zero.